# How to send/receive Message to/from particular ibm mq queue using JMS

Tags: jms

Currently I am using ‘onMessage’ to listen dedicated queue for message.

Now new requirement is, 
1.  different vendor will put msg on single queue, and  I have to differentiate the msg by vendor and store into oracle db.
2.  Second requirement is to send back msg on single queue so particular vendor will pick up.

I am new to this.
Any response is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1) Ask your vendor to set a property, say "Vendor Name", on the message. Then you can use that property to differentiate by vendor. If property can not be set on a message, then you will have to parse the message payload and update database accordingly.

2) Ask your vendor to set `JMSReplyTo` property on the message they are putting in the queue. You can then use the value of the `JMSReplyTo` to send a reply back to vendor. Also you need to take the `JMSMessageID` of the vendor's message and set it as `JMSCorrelationID` of the reply message your application is sending. This way your vendor can correlate the request message with the reply message you sent.

Hope this helps.

Comment: To set Message property as "Vender Name". its work for me.

Comment: i have another doubt
suppose i am sending back msg for 4 number of venders on single queue.
suppose vender 1 application is up and he picked up the msg for vender 1, but 
vender 2 application is down he wont picked up the msg, in this case vender 3 and 4 application will
be able to pick up the message or not as the messages is in sequnce on single queue.
or will it keep waiting until vender 1 to picked up the message as the message on queue is served on FIFO manner.

Comment: Remember you are using a queue, so whichever vendor application comes first, it will get message sitting on top of the queue. It's possible that Vendor1 might get Vendor2's reply message because Vendor2's applicaiton asked for message first. Hence when a queue is shared, applications must get messages using say, matching correlation id. I mentioned in #2 of my answer above.

Comment: On top of the queue vender 2 msg is sitting and then vender 1 and then vender 3. Now vender 2 application is down. In this case will vender 1 and 3 get the msg or not as on top of the queue vender 2 msg is siting and his application is down.

Comment: Corrilation id is set in reply msg for respective vender msg.

Comment: Please read my comment above one more time. Yes, vendor 1 or 3 will get the message on top of the queue, if they are getting messages without matching Correlation ID.

Comment: Yes I understood that vender 1 and 3 will get the message if i dont match the correlation id. But what if the vender 1 application will never up and on top ofthe queue the vender 1 msg will never picked up. So in this case will vender 1 and 3 will keep waiting forever for the the msg ( correlation id matching with vender 1 and 3) which is sitting behind the vender 2 msg on the queue.

Comment: No, Vendor 1 and 3 will not wait as they are getting messages using CorrelationID as selection criteria.